# Show message in current cmd by c#

Tags: c#, console, cmd

I have written the application which works in console as well as a user interface. Now when executing the application from a console, I want to show the message in the currently opened console.

```
static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll",
            EntryPoint = "GetStdHandle",
            SetLastError = true,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll",
            EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",
            SetLastError = true,
            CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern int AllocConsole();
        private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        private const int MY_CODE_PAGE = 437; 

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] Args)
        {
                if (Args[0] != "")
                {
                    //AllocConsole();
                    commandlineTool(Args[0]);
                }
                else
                {

                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Form2());
                }
static void commandlineTool(string filename)
{
    //all coding here
    AllocConsole();

    IntPtr stdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle = new SafeFileHandle(stdHandle, true);
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(safeFileHandle, FileAccess.Write);
    System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(MY_CODE_PAGE);
    StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(fileStream, encoding);
    standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(standardOutput);

    Console.WriteLine("File has been generated.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Actually  **AllocConsole()** allocate new console for the process.

But from this a new console opens and shows the message but I want to show the message in the same console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method A (preferred, easy):**
You can make the application a console application, and release the console if started in GUI mode using [`FreeConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This IMO is the best solution. The *only* drawback is that the console window will be shown very briefly when starting the application.

**Method B (use when necessary):**
You can try to attach to the parent process' console using [`AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). If the parent process doesn't have a console this will fail, in which case you'd have to go back to using AllocConsole.

Also if the [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43zwz7ys.aspx) class has already been initialized when you try to attach/allocate the console, you'll have to re-wire the in/out/error streams like this:

```
    StreamWriter stdOut = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
    stdOut.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetOut(stdOut);

    StreamWriter stdErr = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardError());
    stdErr.AutoFlush = true;
    Console.SetError(stdErr);

    StreamReader stdIn = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());
    Console.SetIn(stdIn);
```

Otherwise you'll have no output.